# How can I get all relationship collection?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

I have 3 model:

- Company, Category, Product.
- HasMany relationship between Company-Category and Product-Category

How can I get all Product from company?

My code:

```
$company = Company::findOrFail($id);
if (isset($company->categories)){
    $categories = $company->categories;
    if (isset($categories->first()->products)){
        $products = $categories->first()->products;
    }
}
```

However my code returns only first category's products.

Comment: Ever heard of "eager loading"?

Comment: @Viney no, I don't know what is this

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of things wrong here.

First, you need to [eager Load](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) your relationships to avoid the N+1 query problem.

Second, if you want to access all the products belonging to all the categories, you cannot call `first()` on the categories relationship. Instead, you need to loop over it.

The following should work.

```
$company = Company::with('categories.products')
    ->findOrFail($id);

if ($company)) {
    foreach ($company->categories as $category) {
        foreach ($category->products as $product) {
            // Access your Product model here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do this

```
 $company = Company::findOrFail($id);
 $categories_ids = $company->category->pluck('id');
 $products = Product::whereIn('category_id',$categories_ids')->get();
```

You maybe can use hasThrouthMany

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            'App\Product',
            'App\Company',
            'category_id', // Foreign key on company table...
            'company_id', // Foreign key on product table...
            'id', // Local key on category table...
            'id' // Local key on company table...
        );
    }
}
```

You can read more info in https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

please try this and let me know how it works :)

Comment: This is many to many...  i think. Eg. Companies has many cateogries, and categories has many products. Any way you can use the first solution.

Comment: Other thing, if you have products in one category but that not corresponds to the company, maybe you need other relation to connect company with products.